# how to install .git file?

Tags: software-installation, git

I `apt-get install git-core`.

I'm trying to install websocketcpp here https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp.

I `wget https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp.git`.

I have no idea what to do next.

(I've read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide and http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/git-install-configure/, but I'm obviously missing something)

Comment: I'm perhaps misreading you, but you do not install a .git file. `.git` is a directory that git uses to track files etc. You typically have the project files and at root level of the project a .git directory where the changes etc are tracked – for the files one tell git to track. When you clone a project you typically get all files that are tracked and also the `.git` directory where all history etc. are present. After clone try e.g. `gitk --all &` at root level. Good read: [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book) e.g. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Comment: @Sukminder Thank you for the extra information!  What's `gitk --all &` for exactly?  I downloaded with jordanm's example and installed from instructions in link.  Does `gitk` keep packages current?

Comment: `gitk` is a graphical fronted for git as a repository browser. (One of many). As starting out it can help to get a view of git and the works. It does not do anything per se. `man gitk`. If it did not come with install of git then depending on system, but typically `apt-get install gitk`.

Comment: @Sukminder oh, cool.  but I have to confess I'm on a 750mb/1.5ghz vps lol.  i think i'm stuck with the command line.  thanks anyways!  i'm sure later readers will very much appreciate!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you actually want to do is `clone` the repository. Here is an example:

```
git clone https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp.git
```

Comment: absolutely perfect!  installation was a breeze after that!

Comment: What command should be used to install a cloned repository?

Comment: @Tarek What do you mean by install? Install the application it contains? That will vary greatly by what the code is.